# How to access plain text content retrieved via <script type="text/plain" src=...> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, text, xss

When using `<script type="text/plain" src="http://..."></script>`, where the URL refers to a plain text file, is there a way to access the content of the file in JavaScript? The file is transferred to the browser, but the value of `innerHTML` property of the `script` element is not changed (it remains the empty string). Inspecting the element node in the DOM does not seem to reveal any property through which the content received could be found.

I know that XMLHTTPRequest can be used instead, but I’m interested in the problem why browsers fetch data in the way I described but do not seem to offer any access to it.

Comment: I'll assume that you're waiting properly for all the content to load and then trying

Comment: I would guess that the browsers don't bother keeping the content *(except perhaps in the browser's cache for a while)*. Once the script has been evaluated, the source isn't needed any more so it would just be wasting memory.

Comment: Interestingly, Chromium doesn't even bother to download external script resources with type attribute being any MIME type not to be interpreted as script as listed here [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#scriptingLanguages] then I wonder why do all this [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#the-script-block-s-source]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the `text`attribute of the `HTMLScriptElement` is the preferred method to access the text of an inline `<script>` element. [DOM-Level-2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-81598695) and [HTML5: 4.11.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#dom-script-text) both indicate that a script should have an attribute `text` which contains the scripts interior *text*:

> The IDL attribute `text` must return a concatenation of the contents of all the Text nodes that are children of the `script` element (ignoring any other nodes such as comments or elements), in tree order. On setting, it must act the same way as the `textContent` IDL attribute.

Since the `<script>` element is empty (you specified an external source), `text`, `textContent` and `innerHTML` are empty. This is because the `text` attribute is only set in inline scripts:

> If the script is inline and the script block's type is a text-based language:
>
> > The value of the `text` IDL attribute at the time the element's "already started" flag was last set is the script source.

So it's not possible to include an external `text/plain` using this method.

See also:

- [W3C: HTML5: 4.11.1 The script element: text attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#dom-script-text) and the example for the game map:

  > ```
  > <script src="game-engine.js"></script> <!-- game engine isn't inline -->
  > <script type="text/x-game-map"> <!-- but data needs to be inline -->
  > ........U.........e
  > o............A....e
  > .....A.....AAA....e
  > .A..AAA...AAAAA...e
  > </script>
  > ```

Comment: This sounds convincing. It does not prove that there is no way to access the loaded content, but it makes that very probable. And as @toofast mentions, Chrome does not even load it.

Answer (score 9):

Note that if this were supported, it would provide a huge security hole and a means of getting around cross-site scripting protections that protect json and other data. Essentially, my nasty web page (nasty.com, say) could access your private data that's protected by cookies by loading it using a script tag. e.g.

```
<script type="text/plain" 
       src="https://supersecure.com/youraccount/privatedocs/list"/>
```

Since the cookies for supersecure.com will automatically be sent with the request (as is the case when requesting any resources), the secure site just returns the data (e.g. the list of private docs) since it couldn't easily tell the  request apart from one from an ajax request from its legitimate webpage. This hole doesn't exist with ajax, since the browser will simply prevent a page from nasty.com from making an ajax request to supersecure.com, thanks to the same origin policy.

Obviously, there's no security problem with inline data.

Answer (score 4):

After several days of researching the same question, I found several references to the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var extText = window.frames.messageTxt.document.body.lastChild.lastChild.data;
      extText = extText.replace(/[\r\n]/g, " ");
      document.forms[0].nMessage.value = extText;
    }
    window.onload = init;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe name="messageTxt" src="txtData.txt" style="display:none"></iframe>
  <form>
    <textarea name="nMessage"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="click" onClick="init()">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code does actually access the txtData.txt file (provided it exists) and dumps it into a `<textarea>` as the default text. For some reason, none of the above responses mention that this works, I assume because the question seems to imply the `<src>` tag specifically (for a similar technique may not be available; I have not checked); however, I still think it is worth mentioning supposing your query pretains to the more general question of obtaining an external .txt file (or if anyone else who comes across this page is seeking said question's anwser), mostly because it took me hours researching it, so I believe it plausible that the answer was simply hard to produce.

Comment: You are right, my question reflects a more general problem, and the use of `iframe` is an interesting approach to that (though it does not work in Chrome for local files, and it is normally subject to cross-origin restriction – effectively, it’s like “Ajax light” with HTML embedding). The assignment to `extText` is the most essential code here—for getting at the text content, the rest depends on what we want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, no I don't think you can get the text content like that. It's mainly because you're going to use dom access elements to get some text that was never really injected into the dom itself.

I tried a few options and they didn't work. I don't have a solid reason why you won't be able to find it, but the reason why i'm giving up / thinking like this is because even the WebKit inspector that i'm using doesn't have a triangle disclosure next to a script-src tag. What it does do is that it converts the src into a link that you can click on and then it uses Ajax or whatever to read that text back from the server.