# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" for my code but existing code work fine in javascript?

Tags: html, css, underscore.js

I am using underscore.js to template my code.Their is some html code written in file that is worked already fine.

when I write this code then javascript refuse to run it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id='tmpl_experiment_schdule'>
        <div>
                </div>
</script>
```

can someone explain me how other people code work and mine just open closed div break to run.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not allowed to use HTML code outside of a string inside of a `<script type="text/javascript">` element. The symbol `<` is used as a comparison operator, not as a `tag starting token`.

Since you didn't provide a left hand side `<` is unexpected. The parser expects something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
2 < 4;
</script>
```

Comment: actually you can have html inside script tags.. but not of type="text/javascript" ;)

Comment: @GungFoo: Well, that's true, but I haven't seen a productive site which uses text/plain or text/html, except for some [experimental features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760852/how-to-access-plain-text-content-retrieved-via-script-type-text-plain-src/12761170#12761170) ^^"...

Comment: kendoUI uses script tags to store html templates for individual rows of i.e. a list-view. check it out! (then you will have seen a productive..... ;)

Comment: Oh, I see `type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"`. Definitely interesting. And the stray smile in their code just made my day :D