# Is it possible to access script tag content when "SRC'ed"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a simple [**test(jsbin)**](http://jsbin.com/AjEdOwo/4/edit) with :

```
 <script id='a' type="text/javascript">
   {a:1} //dummy value
   var a=1;
 </script>
```

And then :

`alert($("#a").text());`

The result was :

[image]

However  - is there any way to access the content when using `src` **using script tag** ?

example :

`<script id='a' src="myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This NOT seems to be working

In other words :

> if you have `<script src="src">contents</script>` - how to get "contents"

Comment: Yes, using ajax to get the file if it's on the same domain.

Comment: @adeneo my question is about script tag.

Comment: And so is my answer ?

Comment: No, your answer is about getting the contents of the script file, not the tag/element.

Comment: @Esailija Hi:-) is it possible ?

Comment: @Esailija - Wasn't that the question? Otherwise, just do `document.getElementById('a').outerHTML` to get the script tag, but that doesn't get you the content of the file ?

Comment: @adeneo What I believe the question is: if you have `<script src="src">contents</script>` - how to get `"contents"`?

Comment: @Esailija right. i'll emphesize that.

Comment: There can't be any contents when the tag has a source ?

Comment: Reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760852/how-to-access-plain-text-content-retrieved-via-script-type-text-plain-src.

Comment: @adeneo well physically you can - accessing it is different story

Comment: @Esailija - If by physically, you mean it can be typed, that's true, but the content is not executed when the script tag has a source, and it's not valid, so technically, no you can't do that. The way to get the content of a script tag with a source is with ajax.

Comment: @adeneo Getting the contents executed when there is a src wasn't the problem but getting the contents as a string somewhere. If you want to execute the contents, you can then do so via eval or such. I don't know why you would even do this if you wanted them to be executed anyway - this would just be nice for having associated data to a script file that it operates on .

Comment: Adding content between the script tags when there is a source is just wrong. It's not valid, it will not be executed, and there's no good reason to do so. Still, I don't see the problem -> http://jsfiddle.net/CKbWu/

Comment: @adeneo well it is mainly to avoid a second script tag for e.g. the JSON configuration like `<script type="text/json" id="configuration-for-script-xyz">{}/script>` The script referenced in src could then easily retrieve its configuration without even using an id but instead self-referencing the tag through `document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]`.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script),

**Script tag**

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. script elements with an src attribute specified **should not** have a script embedded within its tags.