# How to download a JavaScript file without parsing it?

Tags: javascript, performance, webpagetest

To improve performance, I want to prefetch a 1.2 MB legacy JavaScript library on my login page. This library is only needed after the user logs in. WebPageTest shows me that Chrome it takes about 700ms of CPU to process the file after it is downloaded. Is it possible to cache the file on the user's browser, but NOT execute/parse the JavaScript?

My ideal flow:

- load the login page
- async load the js library using the `async` and `defer` attributes of the script tag

  - do not parse, the library isn't actually used until after the user logs in
- user logs in
- load the user's home page & load the js library from cache (if present, otherwise fetch from server - not async) and parse

  - I'd like to only pay the 700ms parsing time here

I looked into possibly changing the "type" of the script attribute to `text/plain` but it seems that [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760852/how-to-access-plain-text-content-retrieved-via-script-type-text-plain-src). Even if this did work it seems to me I would be faced with some sort of `eval` evil.

Why do I want to do it this way? I have a small window of time where the browser is essentially idle while the user types their credentials.  I would like to use that time to download this big library to get a head start loading the next page. I can hydrate the browser's cache by downloading the file in the background, but there is a 700ms spike in CPU that happens after the browser receives the library and parses/executes the file. I would like to avoid this CPU spike on the login page.

You can see the CPU spike on the bottom right of this WPT screen cap:
[image]

Comment: Wrap the contents of the file in a function, include the file before `</body>` in the usual fashion. When the user logs in, execute the function.

Comment: Why are u looking to do this hackiness? If you put the `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>` (as you should be doing for JS) you won't have delay of rendering, which it sounds like is ur problem.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - the rendering is good - about 1.3 seconds to completion. The CPU spike makes the browser less responsive to user interaction for the duration of the spike - I added a screen shot to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @adeneo if I inline the file it won't be cached which is my objective...

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be cached when added right before `</body>` like any other file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/path/to/your/script.js");
req.send(); // This line fetches the file
```

If you want to do something with the contents of this file,
set `req.onload` before the `.send()` line:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/path/to/your/script.js");
req.onload = function()
{
    console.log(this.response);
}
req.send(); // This line fetches the file
```

Finally, on the server-side, make sure the file is cacheable.

Comment: You are exactly right - using a XHR hydrates the cache but does not execute the JS. I used the snippit from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html to round out this approach.

Comment: Another approach could be using browser resource hints
<link rel="prefetch" href="(url)">.
This has pretty good browser support. [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch)